# Unable to get value (post) with jquery.post

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a little problem in order to get some values from a page.

I have the following jQuery UI script :

```js
 $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "slideUp",
        hide: "slideDown",
        height: "300",
        width: "400",
        title: "Test pop-up",
        buttons: {
            "Close": function(){
                $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            }           
        );

    $( "p.diag").click(function(e) {
        var monUrl = 'test2.php';
        $.post("test2.php", { name: "test", time: "test" } );
        $('#dialog').load(monUrl, function(response, status) {
        $('#test_dialog').html(response);
        pos = $("p.diag").attr("id");       
    });
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog("open");      
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

The test2.php page looks like this :

```php
<?php
$var = $_POST['name'];
echo 'name = '.$var.'';
?>
```

I just want to retrieve the "name" value from my jQuery Script, but whatever I do, the `$_POST['name']` remains void...

Any clue ? Am-I doing something wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: where have you seen tgat this is void? use `firebug` or something like this

Answer (score 4):

You don't have callback handler in your code.

```
$.post("test2.php", { name: "test", time: "test" }, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

use this method for take response from php
You did wrong

```
 $.post("test2.php", { name: "test", time: "test" },function(data){
  $('#test_dialog').html(data);  
  });
```